# stop eclipse java formatter from collapsing spaces in comments

Tags: eclipse, comments, formatter

---

When I use Eclipse's java-conventions built-in java formatter, the formatter collapses multiple spaces into one space.

For example the following comment is

```
//              5
//             / \
//            4   8
//           /   / \
//          11  13  4
//         /  \      \
//        7    2      1
```

is modified into after pressing ctrl + shift + f(windows)

```
// 5
// / \
// 4 8
// / / \
// 11 13 4
// / \ \
// 7 2 1
```

How to configure Eclipse to not collapse the extra space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious solution is to disable line comment formatting.

There is a trick that works with the default configuration - you can use non-breaking space characters instead of normal space. You can type it in LibreOffice Writer or MS Word by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Space, then copy the character and paste it into your java comment. This character may not be available in some encodings.